# GCS storage signed url v4, m4a file upload is corrupted, but mp3 is good. python

Tags: google-cloud-storage, multipartform-data, pre-signed-url

### Goal

upload a large(>40mb) m4a audio files to Google Cloud Storage(GCS)

#### Method

1. get the signed url from the backend
2. from the front end, direct upload to GCS with signed url

#### Result

- The mp3 files upload OK, and can play OK via GCS UI.
- The m4a files upload OK, and is corrupted, cannot play. I download the m4a file from GCS, and play from my mac/pc, and fails.
- This is consistent across various mp3 and m4a file sizes.

Any idea how to get m4a files to upload?

```
# python backend
bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(filename)

signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(
            version="v4",
            expiration=timedelta(minutes=60),
            method="PUT",
)
```

```
// front end react JS
async function upload(file: File, signed_url: str) {
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('file', file)

  await axios.put(signed_url, formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': file.type
        },
  })
}
```

Comment: If you download the object from GCS and compare it to the original, are the files different? Is the data different or do they have different sizes? If the file sizes are different, is one of the files a subset of the other?

Comment: sizes are different. with formdata, some data is added to the start of the file.

Answer (score 0):

dont use formdata.
read up on this which is a slightly different problem: [Uploading an MP3 using DropZone.js to Google Cloud Storage via signedUrl is corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602133/uploading-an-mp3-using-dropzone-js-to-google-cloud-storage-via-signedurl-is-corr?rq=2)

```
// front end react JS
async function upload(file: File, signed_url: str) {
  await axios.put(signed_url, file, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': file.type
        },
  })
}
```